# User input through pictureboxes and radiobuttons

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

please bear with me as this is the first time I am writing a question out on here. I am working on a project for my C# object oriented programming class and I am having trouble creating the required methods to handle user input.

I have a windows form with 6 pictureBoxes and 6 RadioButtons. Each of the radio buttons has a value and the user must select the picturebox and then a cooresponding radio button. I am currently using switch cases inside private methods to verify input and keep the data matched until all of the radioButtons are used up. I am running into the issue where the if statements are only allowing picture one to accept the value of radiobutton1 instead of being able to pick any radiobutton and fill the label.

```
int RadPicked = 0;

private void RadioButtonSelection(int radPicked)
    {
        switch(radPicked)
        {
            case (1):

                if (RadPicked == 1 && guessButton1.Checked)
                {
                    guessLabel1.Text = guessButton1.Text;
                    guessButton1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 1 && guessButton2.Checked)
                {
                    guessLabel1.Text = guessButton2.Text;
                    guessButton2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 1 && guessButton3.Checked)
                {
                    guessLabel1.Text = guessButton3.Text;
                    guessButton3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 1 && guessButton4.Checked)
                {
                    guessLabel1.Text = guessButton4.Text;
                    guessButton4.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 1 && guessButton5.Checked)
                {
                    guessLabel1.Text = guessButton5.Text;
                    guessButton5.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 1 && guessButton6.Checked)
                {
                    guessLabel1.Text = guessButton6.Text;
                    guessButton6.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select an image before selecting an answer.");
                }

                break;
            case (2):

                if (RadPicked == 2 && guessButton1.Checked)
                {
                    guess2Label.Text = guessButton1.Text;
                    guessButton1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 2 && guessButton2.Checked)
                {
                    guess2Label.Text = guessButton2.Text;
                    guessButton2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 2 && guessButton3.Checked)
                {
                    guess2Label.Text = guessButton3.Text;
                    guessButton3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 2 && guessButton4.Checked)
                {
                    guess2Label.Text = guessButton4.Text;
                    guessButton4.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 2 && guessButton5.Checked)
                {
                    guess2Label.Text = guessButton5.Text;
                    guessButton5.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 2 && guessButton6.Checked)
                {
                    guess2Label.Text = guessButton6.Text;
                    guessButton6.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select an image before selecting an answer.");
                }
                break;
            case (3):
                if (RadPicked == 3 && guessButton1.Checked)
                {
                    guess3Label.Text = guessButton1.Text;
                    guessButton1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 3 && guessButton2.Checked)
                {
                    guess3Label.Text = guessButton2.Text;
                    guessButton2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 3 && guessButton3.Checked)
                {
                    guess3Label.Text = guessButton3.Text;
                    guessButton3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 3 && guessButton4.Checked)
                {
                    guess3Label.Text = guessButton4.Text;
                    guessButton4.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 3 && guessButton5.Checked)
                {
                    guess3Label.Text = guessButton5.Text;
                    guessButton5.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 3 && guessButton6.Checked)
                {
                    guess3Label.Text = guessButton6.Text;
                    guessButton6.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select an image before selecting an answer.");
                }
                break;
            case (4):
                if (RadPicked == 4 && guessButton1.Checked)
                {
                    guess4Label.Text = guessButton1.Text;
                    guessButton1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 4 && guessButton2.Checked)
                {
                    guess4Label.Text = guessButton2.Text;
                    guessButton2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 4 && guessButton3.Checked)
                {
                    guess4Label.Text = guessButton3.Text;
                    guessButton3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 4 && guessButton4.Checked)
                {
                    guess4Label.Text = guessButton4.Text;
                    guessButton4.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 4 && guessButton5.Checked)
                {
                    guess4Label.Text = guessButton5.Text;
                    guessButton5.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 4 && guessButton6.Checked)
                {
                    guess4Label.Text = guessButton6.Text;
                    guessButton6.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select an image before selecting an answer.");
                }
                break;
            case (5):
                if (RadPicked == 5 && guessButton1.Checked)
                {
                    guess5Label.Text = guessButton1.Text;
                    guessButton1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 5 && guessButton2.Checked)
                {
                    guess5Label.Text = guessButton2.Text;
                    guessButton2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 5 && guessButton3.Checked)
                {
                    guess5Label.Text = guessButton3.Text;
                    guessButton3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 5 && guessButton4.Checked)
                {
                    guess5Label.Text = guessButton4.Text;
                    guessButton4.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 5 && guessButton5.Checked)
                {
                    guess5Label.Text = guessButton5.Text;
                    guessButton5.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 5 && guessButton6.Checked)
                {
                    guess5Label.Text = guessButton6.Text;
                    guessButton6.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select an image before selecting an answer.");
                }
                break;
            case (6):
                if (RadPicked == 6 && guessButton1.Checked)
                {
                    guess6Label.Text = guessButton1.Text;
                    guessButton1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 6 && guessButton2.Checked)
                {
                    guess6Label.Text = guessButton2.Text;
                    guessButton2.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 6 && guessButton3.Checked)
                {
                    guess6Label.Text = guessButton3.Text;
                    guessButton3.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 6 && guessButton4.Checked)
                {
                    guess6Label.Text = guessButton4.Text;
                    guessButton4.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 6 && guessButton5.Checked)
                {
                    guess6Label.Text = guessButton5.Text;
                    guessButton5.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 6 && guessButton6.Checked)
                {
                    guess6Label.Text = guessButton6.Text;
                    guessButton6.Enabled = false;
                }
                else if (RadPicked == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select an image before selecting an answer.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void AnswerSelection(int picked)
    {
        switch (picked)
        {
            case (1):
                RadPicked = 1;

                break;
            case (2):
                RadPicked = 2;

                break;
            case (3):
                RadPicked = 3;

                break;
            case (4):
                RadPicked = 4;

                break;
            case (5):
                RadPicked = 5;

                break;
            case (6):
                RadPicked = 6;

                break;
        }
    }

    private void box1PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnswerSelection(1);
    }

    private void box2PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnswerSelection(2);
    }

    private void box3PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnswerSelection(3);
    }

    private void box4PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnswerSelection(4);
    }

    private void box5PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnswerSelection(5);
    }

    private void box6PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AnswerSelection(6);
    }

    private void guessButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonSelection(1);
    }

    private void guessButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonSelection(2);
    }

    private void guessButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonSelection(3);
    }

    private void guessButton4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonSelection(4);
    }

    private void guessButton5_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonSelection(5);
    }

    private void guessButton6_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButtonSelection(6);
    }
```

Thank you to anyone who has the time to look at this and help me.
@3:53AM EST Edited to show new mostly working code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) . Please Mention exactly where you are facing problem

Comment: I guess my problem lies in how the radio button selection is sending the info to the if statements. Now it seems that the only time i can get the string from the radio button to populate the guess labels is if the number of the radiobutton matches the number of the picturebox. I have been able to brute force other values into there via rapid clicking but this is not ideal.